# Add security restriction sub in the PXSelector declaration

Tags: acumatica

In acumatica, we have the possibility to filter analytical sections based on certain user rights via the menu GL104030.

I configured the sub restrictions from the screen GL104030.
I would like to add the restriction in the parameter below

```
#region Usranalytique
   [PXDBInt]
   [PXDefault]
   [PXSelector(typeof(Sub.subID),typeof(Sub.subCD),typeof(Sub.description),DescriptionField = typeof(Sub.description), SubstituteKey = typeof(Sub.subCD))]  
   [PXUIField(DisplayName="Analytique")]
public virtual int? Usranalytique { get; set; }
public abstract class usranalytique : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<usranalytique> { }
#endregion
```

[image]

Where I can find the description of this :     [SubAccount(typeof(SOOrder.cashAccountID), typeof(SOOrder.branchID), true)]

Comment: Do you have BranchID in your table? maybe this is what you are missing? It might add the restriction you are looking for automatically.

Comment: Brendan, I want just add this field on the head of the SO.301.000. So I have BranchID

Comment: Row level security restrictions are managed with help of function Match of BQL.

Comment: Wonderful ! It's the good function !!! Thanks Yuriy [PXSelector(typeof(Search<Sub.subID, Where<Match<Current<AccessInfo.userName>>>>),typeof(Sub.subCD),typeof(Sub.description),DescriptionField = typeof(Sub.description), SubstituteKey = typeof(Sub.subCD))]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you don't want to use Where statement in your field declaration. But anyway, if you want to use PXRestrictor, consider the code below:

```
  #region Usranalytique
  [PXDBInt]
  [PXDefault]
  [PXSelector(
        typeof(Search<Sub.subID,
            Where<Sub.active, Equal<True>>>),
        typeof(Sub.subCD),
        typeof(Sub.description),
        DescriptionField = typeof(Sub.description),
        SubstituteKey = typeof(Sub.subCD)
    )]
    [PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<Sub.active, Equal<True>>), "The Sub is not active.")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Analytique")]
    public virtual int? Usranalytique { get; set; }
    public abstract class usranalytique : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<usranalytique> { }
    #endregion
```

Comment: Thanks for you return Yuriy, but i wand add row level security.

Comment: Then rephrase you original question, as it is not obvious what you want to achieve

Comment: Yuriy, I update the question. Thanks.